# Fullcalendar refetch eventsource

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

As the title says, I have a question regarding EventSource in the fullcalendar.

At the moment I can load 1 google calendar in the fullcalendar. And know how to add multiple google calendars.

However, I want to use checkboxes (linked to their own google calendar), I dynamically create an array with the googleCalendarIds, all this works, but I can't get the calendar to "refetch" all the event from the google calendars in the array.

At the moment, this is the code I use to populate the calendar:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var selected = [];
$('.badgebox:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push({
        'googleCalendarId' : $(this).val(),
        'className' : $(this).data('color')
    });
});
$('.badgebox').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        selected.push({
            'googleCalendarId' : $(this).val(),
            'className' : $(this).data('color')
        });
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
    }else{
        index = selected.findIndex(obj => obj.googleCalendarId === $(this).val());
        selected.splice(index, 1);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
    }
});
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    header: {
        center: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek'
    },
    views: {
        dayGridMonth: {
            titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }
        }
    },
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'bootstrap', 'googleCalendar' ],
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'api key',
    eventSources: selected,
    eventClick: function(info) {
        info.jsEvent.preventDefault();
    },
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    weekNumbers: true,
    locale: 'nl',
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    nowIndicator: true
});

calendar.render();
```

});

But what I am getting is an error:

```
TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
```

I have loaded all the files needed (and can see they are loaded).

**Edit current code**

This is the code I use now, but still not sure how to fix the resources part (refreshing):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var curSource = [];
    $('.badgebox:checked').each(function() {
        curSource.push({
            'googleCalendarId' : $(this).val(),
            'className' : $(this).data('color')
        });
    });
    var newSource = [];
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'key',
        header: {
            center: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek'
        },
        views: {
            dayGridMonth: {
                titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }
            }
        },
        plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'bootstrap', 'googleCalendar', 'resourceTimeGrid', 'resourceDayGrid' ],
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'apikey',
        eventSources: curSource,
        eventClick: function(info) {
            info.jsEvent.preventDefault();
        },
        defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
        weekNumbers: true,
        locale: 'nl',
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
        nowIndicator: true
    });
    $('.badgebox').on('change', function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
            newSource.push({
                'googleCalendarId' : $(this).val(),
                'className' : $(this).data('color')
            });
        }else{
            index = newSource.findIndex(obj => obj.googleCalendarId === $(this).val());
            newSource.splice(index, 1);
        }
        curSource = newSource;
        calendar.getEventSources().forEach(eventSource => {
            eventSource.remove()
        });
        calendar.addEventSource(curSource);
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: `$(...).fullCalendar` is the jQuery-based syntax from fullCalendar version 3. Look at your own code...how did you create the calendar? Not by using jQuery, certainly. You created it using `calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar` ...and you got the `calendar` variable as a return value, representing the calendar object. So if you want to do anything to the calendar, then you call the method from that object. There are numerous examples of this in the documentation - as well as in your own code (e.g. `calendar.render()`...).

Comment: Once you fix that, you'll find the code still doesn't do what you expect because 1) you aren't using _resources_ (so "refetchResources" is not what you need), and 2) you haven't actually changed any event sources in the calendar. When you wrote `eventSources: selected`, it passes the content of `selected` as it was at that exact moment, and copies it into fullCalendar. it doesn't maintain a reference back to the original variable. Modifying `selected` will not update fullCalendar.

Comment: If you want to change the event sources loaded in the calendar (after the first initialisation), you need to use the methods listed here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source (at the bottom, under "methods")

Comment: @ADyson, thanks for your feedback. I have updated my code (I currently use), as I can't get the refresh to work. The variable "curSource" is updated (can see that in a console.log), but the calendar is not refreshing with the new source (or keep empty if no resource available).

Comment: I think maybe you forgot to take into account the remark where I said refetchResources() wasn't the function you need... :-)

Comment: @ADyson, I have updated my last code, it now removes when I uncheck a checkbox, but when I check it again, the "addEventSource" doesn't add the source again (I checked the curSource in the console and contains the array with the googlecalendar information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic for adding and removing event sources is flawed - it'll remove all the previous sources, but only ever add the currently selected one (well, except that you never clear `newSource` so it'll contain all sorts of duplication after a while). The other problem is that when you write `calendar.addEventSource(curSource);` you're adding an *array* of event sources (even though it only ever contains one item) but adding it as if it was a single event source *object*. Therefore it's not in the format fullCalendar expects, so it doesn't add anything.

Instead you can just use the same logic you use when you first declare the calendar, to loop through all the currently selected checkboxes and set all of them as the current sources. This is the simplest way to do it. Just move that logic into a function so you can re-use it. It also removes the necessity for global objects containing the list of sources. Something like this:

```
  function getEventSources() {
    var sources = [];
    $(".badgebox:checked").each(function() {
      sources.push({
        id: $(this).val(),
        'googleCalendarId' : $(this).val(),
        className: $(this).data("color")
      });
    });
    return sources;
  }
```

Then in the calendar config, set the initial event sources by calling the function:

```
eventSources: getEventSources(),
```

And handle the "change" event on the checkboxes like this:

```
  $(".badgebox").on("change", function() {
    //remove event sources
    calendar.getEventSources().forEach(eventSource => {
      eventSource.remove();
    });
    //get currently selected sources
    var sources = getEventSources();

    //add each new source to the calendar
    sources.forEach(eventSource => {
      calendar.addEventSource(eventSource);
    });
  });
```

I made a live demo here: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/Jjoovym. I couldn't use google calendars for the demo obviously so I've done it with hard-coded lists of events, but the overall logic of the process is identical.

Comment: yes that works. I made it too complicated. Thanks for you help.